# ActionBar not shown on Android Studio preview with AppCompat v22.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

I'm new to Android. I encounter a problem in Android Studio 1.3.1. I can't preview my ActionBar at any preview. As in title, i use AppCompat v22.2.1 and minSDK set to 11 or 15.

With API 15 preview, actionBar is not shown and there is a "Rendering Problems" with "**Couldn't resolve resource @style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode (2 similar errors not shown)**". Following other answers, I changed to Holo Dark theme then I have "**Couldn't resolve resource @style/Widget.Holo.ActionMode (2 similar errors not shown)**"

With API 19 preview, the top bar completely disappeard! Then I changed to Holo theme and the top bar displays but still not the ActionBar.

With API 22 preview, no ActionBar too.

This is my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.primegarage_mada.primegarage"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

In Style.xml :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

My very simple Menu :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".Accueil">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

In my java file :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accueil);
    }
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_accueil, menu);
        return true;
        //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

And when does we need return true and return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)?

I really need to preview, for i can't run now.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: how about including where you initialize the ActionBar (onCreate() likely)

Comment: In your IDE choose the Apptheme as the preview theme

Comment: What is your `Activity` extending?

Comment: @Booger I've edited the post. As you see, it's a very very basic app but the preview doesn't work.

Comment: The first theme i tested with is Apptheme and still not work.

Comment: I extended AppCompatActivity

Comment: I finally struggle to run a virtual device with my extra-slow pc and it's run perfectly in runtime!!!! But still not rendered in preview on android studio! a bug?